# Does the Gunner Mod from the Pathfinder Armor work on stationary guns in addition to vehicle guns

Tags: halo-4

Some turrets have an overheat element just like those found on vehicles.  Does the gunner mod improve stationary gun overheat, or does it just work on vehicles and improve walking speed with detached turrets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Halopedia says,

> When using mounted anti-infantry guns, the weapon overheats less
>   quickly, allowing for longer firing at the maximum rate of fire. Also
>   it allows the player to move faster when the weapon is detached
>   allowing for more offensive tactics rather than defensive.

I am yet to unlock any speciazation to get access to this ability to test it out but if the quote above it to be believe then yes, it does affect stationary guns (MG Turret, Shade).

Comment: As another source of evidence that they count, getting kills with the MG turret whether fixed or on the Warthog counts towards the mounted gun commendation.

Comment: Based on CaulynDarr's additional comment I feel like this is answered even without having the armor mod to test.  It would be very odd to have all things turret apply the same except with this armor mod.

Answer (score 1):

It overheats less quickly, damage seems increased by a little and you move faster. I read it also makes your guy move faster as well but I dont see a change. I have yet to have a foot race to test it out. I like it on big team battles, other then that it has no use.